# Privileges needed to create schema (Oracle)

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, privileges, account

I want to import schema to my new host. First I had created new user account:

```
CREATE USER test IDENTIFIED BY test;
```

What kind of privileges I need to grant to have super role?

(create schema, tables, packages, triggers...etc)

It's one privilege to grant me access to all of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should grant only those privileges that are required for a newly created user to work. One by one.

`CREATE SESSION` is the first one; without it, user can't even connect to the database.
`CREATE TABLE` is most probably also required, if user TEST is going to create his own tables. 
That's enough to get it started. Once it appears that user needs to create a procedure, you'll grant `CREATE PROCEDURE`. And so forth.

There are/were roles named `CONNECT` and `RESOURCE` which contained the "most frequent" privileges one needed, but their use is - as far as I can tell & in my opinion - discouraged.

Comment: DBA - contains all privilege ?

Comment: DBA role contains database system privileges. It is a powerful role, and should **NOT** be granted to anyone but database administrators. Therefore, my answer would be "No" - twice, as "no, you most probably shouldn't grant it to user TEST" and "no, it doesn't contain all privileges".